# How to plot data with a customized log scale in Octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave, loglog

I want to plot data with the scales appearing in this image, which are log scales but somehow adjusted or customized.

[image]

I'm working on Octave, I think a Matlap code should work.
Thanks

Comment: I've tried loglog :
loglog(x,y); grid on ; axis([0.01 90 0.1 90]);

However, this does not give the scales I want.For ex, I want 10 to be located in the middle of the X-axis, and I want y-axis as it appear in the image.
I've notices that loglog is scaling based on natual logarithm not decimal one.

Comment: Add more, the scales are labeled with 1e-3 1e-2 ... I want to label them with decimal nimbers , or at least 10^0 10^1 .. I can not figure out how